# strutsを使用して選択リストを動的に変更する方法について

Tags: javascript, jsp, struts

現在strutsの学習をしています。
現状では、
「A.jsp」に存在するボタンを押下すると、
「B.jsp」へ遷移し、DBからデータを取得した値を選択リストの中に入れている状態です。
そこで、ここから「選択リスト１」の値を変えると、
自動的に「選択リスト２」の値が「選択リスト１」の値に対応した値のみに
変更されるというものを作りたいと思っています。

・選択リスト１　→ここを変えると下の選択リスト２の値が変更される。
・選択リスト２

そこで、javascriptのonchangeを使用して、
actionクラスを呼び出そうとしているのですが、
どうしても表示ができません。
そこで以下の点についてお聞きしたいです。

・onchangeを使用してactionクラスを呼び出す方法
※functionの中身に記述するコードはどのようなものがよろしいのでしょうか。

・使用するactionクラスについて
※現在「A.jsp」のボタンで使用するactionクラス内のif分岐で、
ボタンの処理と「B.jsp」で使用するonchangeでの処理を分岐させようとしているのですが、
そもそものactionクラスを分けてしまった方がよろしいのでしょうか。
（「B.jsp」では別の処理でactionクラスを使用する予定です。）

お手数ですが、教えていただければ幸いです。
宜しくお願い致します。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

回答からずれますが、今から学習するのに`struts1`、`struts2`は古すぎると考えます。
(特に`struts1`はすでにメンテナンスされていない)
JSPを扱うフレームワークであれば、`Spring`をお勧めします。

---

その上で回答します。(フレームワークに依存しない内容と見受けましたので)

選択リスト(`<select>`)の`onchange`イベントでアクションを呼び出すのであれば、
`<select>`の上位の`<form>`要素の`action`属性に呼び出したいactionのURL(パス)を記述しておいて、`onchange`イベントの際にその`form`の`submit`を呼び出すjavascriptコードを実装するとよいかと思います。

＃素のjavascriptかjQueryライブラリを使うかで、書き方が変わるので、例は割愛します。

Comment: ありがとうございます！そうなんですか。。

Comment: ひとまず教えて頂いたことを実践してみます！ありがとうございました！！